# Можно ли задавать от слова "неприязнь" вопрос родительного падежа к объекту неприязни?

Tags: падежи, управление, словосочетания

Можно ли по аналогии со словом "неприятие" сказать "неприязнь человека", "неприязнь электронных книг"? Или тут допустим только дательный падеж, а родительный падеж указывает на субъекта неприязни?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мои изыскания говорят, что нет, нельзя. Требуется предлог *к* или (много реже)  *относительно*.

А личное восприятие - *"неприязнь человека", "неприязнь электронных книг"* - непонятно, кто на ком стоял: то ли книги испытывают неприязнь к эээ... грязной клавиатуре, а человек - к книгам, то ли наоборот, - в общем, объект и субъект меняются местами, образуя сумбур вместо музыки.